# Counting occurrences of elements of one array in another array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I want to find frequency of elements of a given one dimensional numpy array (`arr1`) in another one dimensional numpy array (`arr2`). The array `arr1` contains elements with no repetitions. Also, all elements in `arr1` are part of the array of unique elements of `arr2`

Consider this as an example,

```
arr1 = np.array([1,2,6])
arr2 = np.array([2, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0])
```

At present, I am using the following:

```
freq = np.zeros(  len(arr1)  )

for i in range( len(arr1) ):
    mark = np.where( arr2==arr1[i] )
    freq[i] = len(mark[0])

print freq
>>[2, 4, 1]
```

The aforementioned method gives me the correct answer. But, I want to know if there is a better/more efficient method than the one that I am  following.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a vectorized solution based on [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(arr1,arr2)
idx[idx==len(arr1)] = 0
mask = arr1[idx]==arr2
out = np.bincount(idx[mask])
```

It assumes `arr1` is sorted. If not so, we got two solutions :

1. Sort `arr1` as the pre-processing step. Since, `arr1` is part of unique elements from `arr2`, this should be a comparatively smaller array and hence an inexpensive sorting operation.
2. Use `sorter` arg with `searchsorted` to compute `idx`:

   `sidx = arr1.argsort()`;
   `idx = sidx[np.searchsorted(arr1,arr2,sorter=sidx)]`

Comment: Where `arr1` is assumed to be sorted.

Comment: Thanks. :) `arr1` is assumed to be sorted.

Comment: I get an error ( `IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3`) when I change to `arr1 = np.array([1,2,3])` from `arr1 = np.array([1,2,6])`. I wondering if I am missing something

Comment: @SiddharthSatpathy Needed an edit there. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, Divakar. Your help is much appreciated. :)